# Hide one toggle when another is clicked

Tags: toggle

When using several toggle items on a page (just toggle, not togggleClass etc) how is it possible to close one when another is opened?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggle-trigger").click(function(){
    $(".toggled-div").toggle(300);
    });
});



$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggle-trigger-2").click(function(){
    $(".toggled-div-2").toggle(300);
    });
});
```

So ideally, when toggle-trigger-2 is clicked to toggle toggled-div-2, toggle-trigger-div (the first one) is hidden.